# change style with delay and in a loop

Tags: jquery, css, loops, delay

Im trying to make a div change color in a loop with a little delay between each color change so you can see the color, i have no idea how to do it or what to search for, so now im asking, i have just made a fittle of i how i think i should work, it gives a pretty good idea of what i try to do.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $("#box").css("background-color", "red");
     delay(500);
     $("#box").css("background-color", "yellow");
     delay(500);
     $("#box").css("background-color", "green");
     delay(500);
     $("#box").css("background-color", "purple");
     loop();
});
```

[and the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fud5r/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'gray'],
    cnt = 0;

    var loop = setInterval(function() {
        if (cnt === colors.lenght) {
            clearInterval(loop);
        }

        $('#box').css('background-color', colors[cnt]);
        cnt++;
    }, 500)
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, just what i need. And i figured out to combine it with some scrolling :)

Comment: I had something similar in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/7ntJw/ ( In this one the first color change after the click has no delay, because I felt that it might be weird if it did. )

Comment: You need to reset cnt somewhere btw

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `window.setInterval()`

```
var colors = ['green','yellow','blue'];

var step = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
    $(".box").css('background-color',colors[step]);
    if(step==colors.length-1) 
        step=0;
    else
        step+=1;
},500);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/NHVcU/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
  $("#box").css("background-color", "red");
     setTimeout(function() {
         $("#box").css("background-color", "yellow");
            setTimeout(function() {
             $("#box").css("background-color", "green");
                setTimeout(function() {
                 $("#box").css("background-color", "purple");
                    $("#button").click();
  },500);},500);},500);},500);});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fud5r/1/)**

Comment: what if you want to use more colors(10 e.g)? It's duplicated code

Comment: well OP would have specified so then. Nobody would prefer the above solution when the number of colors would be more.

Comment: thats not the reason to downvote ok. it is quite possible that one solution could not be feasible than other. but then its a solution for OPs problem.

Comment: @Joonas:Thanks for letting me know that.